# Practical use of composition and interface together in Java?

Tags: java, interface, composition

I am having a difficulty in understanding how to use composition and interface together to favor composition instead of inheritance? An example could be:

Interface:

```
public interface IMachine {
    void TurnOn();
    void TurnOff();
}
```

---

Machine Class is the parent Class of Printer Class

```
public class Machine {

    protected boolean isOn;

    public Machine(boolean isOn) {
        this.isOn = isOn;
    }

    public void TurnOn() {
        isOn = true;
        System.out.println("Machine is on !");
    }

    public void TurnOff() {
        isOn = false;
    }

}
```

---

Now if I create a Printer Class which implements IMachine interface, it will implement the methods of the IMachine interface. But let's say I create a Clock Class that implements IMachine interface, then I have to implement those methods again.Is there a more efficient way where we use composition and interface and delegate the methods to Machine class?

Comment: Easy solution would be... just let `Machine implements IMachine`, set `turnOn()` and `turnOff()` as `final` and let `Printer` and `Clock extends Machine`.

Comment: @Turing85 The point with composition is to *not* use inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With inheritance, you'd have a base class with shared logic, and subclasses using that shared logic. Any public method of that base class is shared API.

With composition, the interface defines the shared API, each implementing class (those that were subclasses before) will delegate those call to a composite class that actually has the shared logic.

*Inheritance*

```
public abstract class Machine {
    public void turnOn() {/*logic here*/}
    public void turnOff() {/*logic here*/}
}
public final class Heater extends Machine {
    // heater methods here
}
```

*Composition*

```
public interface Machine {
    void turnOn();
    void turnOff();
}
final class MachineImpl {
    public void turnOn() {/*logic here*/}
    public void turnOff() {/*logic here*/}
}
public final class Heater implements Machine {
    private MachineImpl impl = new MachineImpl();
    @Override public void turnOn() { this.impl.turnOn(); }
    @Override public void turnOff() { this.impl.turnOff(); }
    // heater methods here
}
```

Users of `Machine` will still see the same public API, and users of `Heater` will still see the same public API, but the logic has been relocated.

This allows `Heater` to implement multiple independent "features", something that wasn't possible when using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Composition is generally referred to in a "has a" relationship.  In this case, composition could be used if you had the concept of a PowerSwitch object, for instance.  This would be fulfilled in the notice that a Machine "has a" PowerSwitch.

Inheritance is more often referred to as an "is a" relationship, as in your Printer "is a" Machine case.

Using a PowerSwitch object, you could encompass the functionality for both a Printer and a Clock, possibly in an AbstractMachine

```
public abstract class AbstractMachine implements IMachine {
  private PowerSwitch machinePowerSwitch;

  public void turnOff() {
    machinePowerSwitch.turnOff();
  }

  public void turnOn() {
    machinePowerSwitch.turnOn();
  }

  public void isOn() {
    return machinePowerSwitch.getPowerState();
  }
}
```

Or something similar to that.  Printer and Clock could then both extend AbstractMachine.

EDIT: Re-reading the question I see you want composition INSTEAD OF inheritance (I was reading it as you were wanting to use both).  In that case, simply use the powerswitch directly in the Printer/Clock classes.